# How should I describe my work on a service that was acqui-hired and shut down?

Tags: resume, linkedin, startup, acquisition

Some time ago, I worked on a service, let's say "Foo", hosted at `foo.com`, on the App Store as "Foo", etc.

The Foo team was [acqui-hired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acqui-hiring) by a much larger company, Bar. While Bar continued to operate Foo for some time, it has since been shut down. `foo.com` now redirects to `bar.com`, and Foo can no longer be found on the App Store.

What is the *best* way to reference this on my résumé and LinkedIn profile, so that people do not go searching for a nonexistent service?

Something like:

> Foo was acquired by Bar in `MM YYYY`, and was shut down in `MM YYYY`.

...at the end of the description of Foo? (my time at Bar has a separate section, since it was really a completely different job)

Comment: Is there any "news" coverage about Bar's acquisition of Foo, or even better, of Foo before the acquisition? Does Foo.com have a Wayback Machine entry or several?

Comment: Yes, plenty of both.

Comment: Related, but not quite a duplicate: [What is the accepted method of indicating a company being acquired on a resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/what-is-the-accepted-method-of-indicating-a-company-being-acquired-on-a-resume)

Comment: Also, [On my resume, how should I refer to an ex-employer that no longer exists?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21229/on-my-resume-how-should-i-refer-to-an-ex-employer-that-no-longer-exists)

Comment: IMO, it's relevant that this was an [acquihire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acqui-hiring), because 1. my job working on the Foo changed almost immediately to a new job and 2. Foo was intended to be shut down/"incredible journey"-ed from the start. I don't think that it can be generalized to all acquisitions.

Comment: @so2 "Acqui-hire" is not a common term, so it is likely the previous editors believed you had made a spelling error. I added the link to your question to make it clear that that is the term you intended to use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are probably already aware of this, but just for clarity, your resume should focus on *your work*, and less on what happened to the product or the company. The latter part *is* important though, since people tend to do an internet search for such things, especially in case of shortlisted resumes.

Describing your "Foo" experience as something *like* the below should do:

> Senior Software Architect for Foo (known as Bar since 06/2015)  -- 01/2011 to 12/2012 
>   * Designed blah blah blah
>   * Implemented 200 widgets for more blah blah blah
>   * Reviewed 10000 lines of code for even more blah blah blah
>   * blah blah blah

Given that mergers and acquisitions are quite common in the industry (and not just in software/IT), any hiring manager qualified enough to read your resume should not be surprised that the "Foo" app doesn't exist any more, if you make it clear enough as above.

I also think it is not necessary to explicitly point out the acquisition date, because (1) it is already clear that the Foo app is now known by the new name of Bar (2) it provides no useful information with regards to the decision to shortlist your resume.

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say that Foo is _known_ as Bar, Bar is a company comparable with Google, and Foo was a single-digit employee startup. It's more that Foo was _consumed_ by Bar, although of course I wouldn't use that language.

Comment: @so2 Then instead of *Known as Bar Since* use *Acquired by Bar in*. They don't need to need to know it was shutdown, if there is enough media coverage, that will come up in their checks.

Comment: Is there a strong reason to place this information in the section header, instead of in the closing sentence of the section's content? I mostly object to it aesthetically, because the parenthetical sticks out compared to all of my other headers.

Comment: @so2 I read the question again, and I realise that I got confused due to "Foo" being used to refer to the app, the company, and the website in different places. Your other point is also a good one, I will make an edit to take care of this. Thanks.